# Typescript promise not resolving correctly before moving on in async code

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await, promise

I am trying to populate the 'documents' object which is just a Documentation array. I first build out a list of Promise and store the values in 'promises' to then call Promise.all on to fire things all off at once. Then for each promise, I try and grab the text value from each response in resolvePromise(), create a document from the value, and push it to documents.

```
type Documentation = { name: string; source: string; rawText: string };
const documents: Documentation[] = [];

async function resolvePromise(entry: Response, documents: Documentation[]) {
        const document = { name: '', source: '', rawText: '' };
        document.rawText = await entry.text(); // entry.text(): Promise<string>
        documents.push(document);
        console.log('documents length is now: ' + documents.length);
}

async function createDocumentsObject() {
    const promises: Promise<Response>[] = [];
    // code to populate promises list

    HELP.forEach((value: ConfigItem[], key: string) => {
        value.forEach((configElem: ConfigItem) => {
            if (!configElem.subsection) {
                const promise = getRequest(configElem.source);
                promises.push(promise);
            }
        });
    });

    console.log('promises: ');
    console.log(promises); // const promises: Promise<Response>[]

    await Promise.all(promises).then(async values => {
        values.forEach(async entry => {
            if (!entry.ok) {
                return Promise.reject();
            } else {
                return await resolvePromise(entry, documents);
            }
        });
    });

    console.log('docs');
    console.log(documents);
}
```

In the print statement below, you can see the promises variable is populated with the promises correctly. However, the call to **console.log(documents);** runs before the calls to resolvePromise(). I tried using **await entry.text();** to get the string value from entry.text() before moving on, but that is not working. I am trying to populate the documents object immediately for use right after in the code. I am new to TS so noob friendly explanations are appreciated!

[image]

Comment: When you have an `async function` you **don't** use `new Promise` - and vice-versa.

Comment: would returning '''return Promise.resolve(entry);''' in resolvePromise() make more sense? either way i tried that to no avail as well @Dai

Comment: @Barry You can just remove the promise alltogether and return nothing. The function is async so it will return a promise automatically that resolves when you return.

Comment: ok i removed the promise entirely from resolvePromise() but the result is the same @Axekan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: Replace `forEach` with a `for .. of` loop and it will work.

Comment: This feels like [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/). You could probably simplify this a lot by combining `getRequest` and `resolvePromise`. Theres no need to await a list of promises and then do another async with each promise individually.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is here:
`values.forEach(async entry => {...})`

`forEach` will not resolve the promises returned by the async function.

I would change it to
`return Promise.all( values.map( async entry => {...} ) )`